# Is it feasible to compress cleaned Biogas?

Tags: thermodynamics, compressed-gases, biogas

Biogas generated from anaerobic digestion mainly contains around 50-60% $CH_4$, 35-40% $CO_2$, small amount of $N_2$, saturated $H_2O$ and trace of $H_2S$. It's upgraded to automotive fuel grade by removing $H_2S$ up to, $H_2O$ and $CO_2$. The upgraded Biogas (contains >90% of $CH_4$ and <4% $CO_2$) is compressed up to 250 bar to bottle, transport and to use as an alternative of Natural Gas.

Now, my question is, is it feasible to compress biogas after cleaning out $H_2S$ and $H_2O$ but without removing $CO_2$ so that it can be bottled and transported? Or what problem can arise while compressing methane with $CO_2$? Up to which pressure can it be compressed?

Comment: CO2 can be compressed to a solid. what more do you expect?

Comment: could go for diamond, where pressure is so intense that it favors the hydrogen from hydrocarbons splitting off and outgassing through just about any material over time... the CO2 would likely turn into some impurities.  Physically feasible does not mean financially sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes. But there are reasons not to do it:

- the vapor pressure of CO<sub>2</sub> at 20°C is about 57 bar, in other words at the high pressures you are talking about you get liquid CO<sub>2</sub>. Makes more sense, then, to remove the CO<sub>2</sub>
- Compression takes energy. Removing the CO<sub>2</sub> before compression saves some of that energy
- Compression generates heat, liquefying CO<sub>2</sub> generates additional heat
- Biogas has a different Wobbe-Index than pure methane, meaning the air-fuel mixture will need to be changed in a consumer that is designed for methane. Often a very minor change, like the setting of a carburetor in  an engine or adjusting a nozzle in a burner, but nonetheless
- You would haul the additional weight of the CO<sub>2</sub> around

As far as I know, the most common biogas upgrading technologies these days are membrane filtration and pressure water scrubbing. However biogas upgrading by CO<sub>2</sub> liquification (by cooling and compression) is or was available on the market (some Swedish company, forgot the name) and used in gas-to-grid plants. These plants would sell the liquid CO<sub>2</sub>.